# Suspend the execution of the angularjs application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How is it possible to pause the execution the entire application at app.run (function () {})?

For example:

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
  .run(function ($timeout) {
     $timeout(function () {
       next(); // While this function is not executed, 
               // the application must not download data and perform any task.
     }, 1000);
   });
```

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: I do not know how to do it =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't if your are bootstrapping your app with `ng-app="frontendApp"`.

However you might be able to it with manual bootstrapping. Instead of `ng-app` in your HTML, use something like this in your script:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     //Bootstrap the application after 3 seconds
     setTimeout(function() {
         angular.bootstrap(document, ['frontendApp']);
     }, 3000);
});
```

There is also a deffered bootstrap process, where you can call `angular.resumeBootstrap()` but I think this is applicable to testing.

More info here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap

Comment: It not possible to pause the views loading, but load services?

Comment: Well this essentially lengthens the bootstrapping process of angular, so nothing would work (meaning the directives won't be compiled and the services won't be created). The HTML page which contains the directives *will* load.